# Parse Python protoBuf binary data (trained model) using Tensorflow and C++

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow

I've a serialized my trained tensorflow model that I obtained from Python using the `tf.train.export_meta_graph().SerializeToString()` function. This gives me a huge string of binary data. Something like the following.

```
b'\n\x9a\x15\x12\x84\x15\n9\n\x03Add\x12\x06\n\x01x"\x01T\x12\x06\n\x01y"\x01T\x1a\x06\n\x01z"\x01T"\x1a\n\x01T\x12\x04type:\x0f\n\r2\x0b\x13\x01\x02\x04\x06\x05\x03\t\x08\x12\x07\n\x83\x01\n\x0cApplyAdagrad\x12\x0b\n\x03var"\x01T\x80\x01\x01\x12\r\n\x05accum"\x01T\x80\x01\x01\x12\x07\n\x02lr"\x01T\x12\t\n\x04grad"\x01T\x1a\x0b\n\x03out"\x01T\x80\x01\x01"\x1d\n\x01T\x12\x04type:\x12\n\x102\x0e\x01\x02\t\x03\x04\x11\x05\x06\x08\x12\x0b\x0c\r\x13"\x17\n\x0buse_locking\x12\x04bool\x1a\x02
```

**Note:** This is not the complete data but just to give you an idea.

Now I want to deserialize this data using the Tensorflow C++ API and I am not sure how to do this. I imported it in Python successfully like this.

**Python**:

```
meta_graph_def = meta_graph_pb2.MetaGraphDef()
meta_graph_def.ParseFromString(data)

with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:
    # new_saver = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def)
    new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(meta_graph_def)
return graph
```

This returns me the correctly initialized graph using the binary data I provided in the `"data"` variable. How can I achieve the same in C++?

**Update:**

I already tried to achieve the same but I get the following error.

```
error: ‘b’ was not declared in this scope
```

Here's the code I am using to achieve the same.

```
tf::GraphDef graph_def;
std::string data = "[the long binary string defined above]";
graph_def.ParseFromString(data);
```

As I know this has something to do with the preceeding `b` in the binary data shown above, shouldn't it be compatible with the `C++ ParseFromString` function from protoBuf since this binary data was generated from the python protoBuf using `SerializeToSTring()`. What could be the reason behind this problem ?

Comment: What sort of help are you looking for? Are you asking for someone to convert that Python into C++?

Comment: hi @halfer, yes exactly. As i wrote in my last line of the question. How can I import the binary data into c++ so that I can start making predictions directly in c++

Comment: Right, that's too much work to ask of volunteers here. That's essentially a request for free labour, which is not the point of Stack Overflow. It is much better for you to make an attempt first, and then ask a more focussed question if you get stuck on something in particular. Are you able to change the question to something more specific?

Comment: well I have already been trying it since the whole day yesterday. And the reason for posting it here was to get some help regarding this. I have been more specific about my issue to the question now. Maybe now if someone could help. Please check the update

Comment: Note that it does not matter how long you've been trying if we do not see an attempt - it looks like you've not tried at all. Your new question is much better, thanks.